# Usage of both is-a and has-a relationship?

Tags: design

So if I have a class called `Object`, a class, `bench`, that derives from `Object`, and finally a class called `Park` that derives from `Object` that has-a `bench` - is this bad "practice", to have two objects that technically both is-a `Object` but still the one uses the other? The reason I ask is because I can seem funny to have two classes *of the same base class* that use each other.

Comment: You mean that you have a _class_ Park, right? Or is that a single object? You seem to confuse the terms slightly. "I have an object" generally means that you have an instance (like a variable, something allocated in memory). This object usually is off some class, though it doesn't necessarily have to (in dynamically language like JavaScript these terms get somewhat fuzzy).

Comment: The potential problem with your design is not that a park can both *be* an object and also *contain* an object. The problem is: by making both bench and park extend the same base class, the base class becomes so general as to be meaningless. **What operation are you going to perform on the characteristics common to both benches and parks?**

Comment: Adding to Eric Lipperts, comment, the use of a common base class depends on the purpose of your framework.  3D environments, for instance, very commonly derive almost every world object from one common ancestor.  The common ancestor typically has rotation, position, and scale, and usually an Identifier/Name. It makes sense in a 3D world where everything shares a spatial relationship.  But that's a very specific case for programming objects.

Comment: have a look at the [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) design pattern

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what language this is but in e.g. Java, all classes extend Object so this isn't really a choice you have to make.

But in general, there's nothing wrong with something being a type and being composed of a type.  For example, a cruise ship is a type of boat and the lifeboats it is required to have to be operational are boats.  A nation is a group of people which is composed of groups of people.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong about having a common base class. This is actually a very common pattern.

In many languages (Java and all derivatives, JavaScript, new Python classes, and countless other) classes are designed in such a way that all objects are derived from a common base (usually called Object).

It is also common for frameworks and libraries to define base classes that many or most other derive from, like for instance QObject in Qt, or models.Model in Django ORM (where models are intended to have has-a relations between them).

Answer (score 2):

> The reason I ask is because I can seem funny to have two classes of the same base class that use each other.

Just some counterexamples that should prove the point:

- A `Boss` is a `Person`. An `Employee` is a `Person`. An `Employee` has a `Boss`.
- A child has a father and a mother, even though they are all just `Person` objects.
- A `Rifle` is a `Weapon`. A `GrenadeLauncher` is a `Weapon`. A `Rifle` can have a  `GrenadeLauncher` attached to it.

There is nothing wrong with this.

I think you see this as funny because in LOB applications, a set of classes is often designed to counterbalance eachother, which often leads to classes representing mutually exclusive roles and thus rarely having any functionality-related shared inheritances.

But this is not the case. And if you delve more into technical-related implementations, which are not designed to implement functionality but rather improve the code standard, you will see that shared inheritances become much more common.